# How to add URL to Bibtex without overfull hbox

Tags: bibtex, errors

I need to add the reference:

```
@website{imageofbell,
author = {Richard Gill},
year = {2013},
title = {Bell},
url="https:/commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bell.svg",
note = "[Online; accessed 10-March-2021]",
}
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
Overfull \hbox (88.23233pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 174--181
[]\tenrm @miscimageofbell, au-thor = Richard Gill, year = 2013, ti-tle = Bell, 
url="https:/commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bell.svg",|
)
*
```

Comment: This depends on your bibliography package and style. Can you please show us a short example document that shows how you generate your bibliography and that reproduces the output/warning you get at the moment?

Comment: Are you loading the `xurl` package? If not, give it a try.